# 301 redirects clashing possibly with CloudFlare

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cloudflare

My old 301 redirects in .htaccess are no longer working because something is redirecting things twice.  Example of redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage.html //www.example.com/newpage.php
```

This used to work, but now it goes to:

```
https://www.example.com//www.example.com/newpage.php
```

In CloudFlare, I have a Page Rule for the www redirection:

```
https://example.com/*
Forwarding URL (Status Code: 301 - Permanent Redirect, Url: https://www.example.com/$1)
```

And my "Always Use HTTPS" in CloudFlare is on.  What could be causing the double redirect?

Comment: I tried turning both of these off in cloudflare, and using a www redirect in .htaccess.  I was still getting the double redirect, and the site wasn't "secure" anymore.  So I tried using a rule in .htaccess for both https and www redirection and that broke the site completely (my ssl certificate is with cloudflare so I guess they have to do that redirect?), so.. I'm back to the original settings.

Comment: Hm, moving the redirects from .htaccess into cloudflare as "page rules" DOES work.  I guess I now have to do everything via cloudflare?  I only have 20 page rules though and I need like 50...

Answer (score 0):

I put one of the URLs into a redirect checker http://www.redirect-checker.org/
and noticed that for some reason the URLs go back to http, then back to https again.  So I went back and edited my .htaccess file to explicitly include the https:

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage.html https://www.example.com/newpage.php
```

And now the redirect works as expected, at least in the incognito window. The regular browser isn't yet reflecting the change.